# The difference in meaning between I used to hate it and I hated it

Tags: difference, usage

What is the difference in meaning between "I used to hate it" and "I hated it"?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases "used to do" and "did" are equivalent. Cases like those just reference something in the past.

> I used to hate my fifth grade teacher.

This is little different from saying "I hated my fifth grade teacher."

In other cases "used to do" is different from simple past in that a continuing situation no longer exists.

> I used to hate broccoli, but now I rather like it.

Meaning there was a time when the speaker hated broccoli, but that time is past, and some kind of conversion to liking broccoli has taken place.

In still another case, "used to do" can refer to a continuing event in the past that no longer obtains.

> I used to hate the weather in Chicago, but since I've been living in Hawaii I have no complaints.

In that case the speaker might still hate the weather in Chicago if he still lived there (or maybe not) but the case is no longer being tested.

Comment: What does **since** mean in the latter case—"because of" or "from that time on"?

Comment: It means "from that time on" there.

Comment: Shouldn't it be _**have had** no complaints_ then? _I have had no complaints since I've been living here._

Comment: It can mean that, but native speakers would usually just use the present tense there.